# DynamoDB ProjectionExpression Set Contains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have table with items which each contain a string set, as well as other information.  Can I query the table and get back a flag if the set contains a particular entry.  I don't want to filter by the set, just find out if it contains an item without pulling back the full set.

For example, say I have the following items:

```
[
    {
        things: { "a", "b" },
        name: "Coffee"
    },
    {
        things: { "b" },
        name: "Tea"
    }
]
```

I would like to query this table with something like `Projection: "flag=(thing CONTAINS 'a'), name"` and get back:

```
[
    {
        flag: true,
        name: "Coffee"
    },
    {
        flag: false,
        name: "Tea"
    }
]
```

Is this possible?